# Best way to refresh and refetch api on a react app

Tags: reactjs, async-await

i'm building a simple react app that fetches the data from the OpenWeather Api. i want to refresh the data received every minute to reflect the changes(if there are any changes) to the app. I tried using setInterval when i call the fetchApi function that i created, but according to the console log it doesn't sound very precise or realiable. This is my part of the code:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const currentData = async () => {
    const currentWeatherData = await fetchCurrentData();
    setCurrentWeather(currentWeatherData);
  };

  const futureData = async () => {
    setFutureWeather(await fetchFutureData())
    console.log(futureWeather);
  };

  currentData();
  futureData();

  setInterval(() => {
    currentData();
    futureData();
    console.log("reloaded!");
  }, 60000);
}, []);
```

How can i improve this code to make it effectively work?
Thanks guys

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You'll likely want to clear that interval in a return function from `useEffect`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you will need to clear the interval in the cleanup of the useEffect function.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const currentData = async () => {
      const currentWeatherData = await fetchCurrentData();
      setCurrentWeather(currentWeatherData);
    };

    const futureData = async () => {
      const futureWeatherData = await fetchFutureData();
      setFutureWeather(futureWeatherData);
    };

    currentData();
    futureData();

    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      currentData();
      futureData();
    }, 60000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: now it's taking more than one minute to refresh. It's possible that setInterval will wait one minute to start the function at the beginning?

Comment: You're running the fetch functions first before the `setInterval` then trigger them every 1 minute. You should check your `network` tab in the devtools to understand what's going on.

Comment: The problem is if i don't call the two functions before the setInterval, i won't have results for one minute before the function is called